# How do I get a list of service method descriptors from a GRPC server given a ManagedChannel?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc

This is sort of the reverse of [Get the list of registered gRPC service name and methods in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63624473/get-the-list-of-registered-grpc-service-name-and-methods-in-python) in that I am trying to pull the list of services and their descriptors from the client side i.e. `ManagedChannel`

What I am trying to do is something like

```java
var c = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("foo").build();
Collection<ServerServiceDefinition> defs = c.listServices();
```

But `ManagedChannel` does not hava a method like that and rightfully so since GRPC I don't think should expose that list by default, but I want to expose it for my use case in which I want to dynamically call an artbitrary service/method without the original PROTO file.

I am thinking there's something called Server Reflection, that provides a low level API from what I can tell and does not provide a specific example to get the information I am looking for.  Also most of the examples for the API shows how to enable it on the server but not provide the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit awkward but it seems to do the first part of what I need to do which is get the reflection data

```java
    managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 50000).usePlaintext().build();
    final var serverReflectionBlockingStub = ServerReflectionGrpc.newStub(managedChannel);

    final var serviceListLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final Set<String> serviceNames = new HashSet<>();
    final var errorRef = new AtomicReference<Throwable>();
    final var serviceListObserver =
        serverReflectionBlockingStub.serverReflectionInfo(
            new StreamObserver<>() {
              @Override
              public void onNext(ServerReflectionResponse value) {

                value.getListServicesResponse().getServiceList().stream()
                    .map(ServiceResponse::getName)
                    .forEach(serviceNames::add);
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(Throwable t) {

                errorRef.set(t);
                serviceListLatch.countDown();
              }

              @Override
              public void onCompleted() {

                serviceListLatch.countDown();
              }
            });
    serviceListObserver.onNext(ServerReflectionRequest.newBuilder().setListServices("*").build());
    serviceListObserver.onCompleted();
    serviceListLatch.await();
    if (errorRef.get() != null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(errorRef.get());
    }

    final var serviceFileLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final var serviceFileProtoObserver =
        serverReflectionBlockingStub.serverReflectionInfo(
            new StreamObserver<>() {
              @Override
              public void onNext(ServerReflectionResponse value) {

                try {
                  var fileDescriptorProto =
                      DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto.parseFrom(
                          value.getFileDescriptorResponse().getFileDescriptorProto(0));
                  for (var serviceDescriptorProto : fileDescriptorProto.getServiceList()) {
                    for (var methodDescriptorProto : serviceDescriptorProto.getMethodList()) {


                      // it is at this point I have the methods already
   
                      var methodDescriptor =
                          methodDescriptorFromProto(
                              fileDescriptorProto, serviceDescriptorProto, methodDescriptorProto);
                      methods.put(
                          new GrpcServiceMethod(
                              serviceDescriptorProto.getName(), methodDescriptorProto.getName()),
                          methodDescriptor);
                    }
                  }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                  errorRef.set(e);
                  serviceFileLatch.countDown();
                }
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(Throwable t) {

                errorRef.set(t);
                serviceFileLatch.countDown();
              }

              @Override
              public void onCompleted() {

                serviceFileLatch.countDown();
              }
            });
    serviceNames.stream()
        .map(name -> ServerReflectionRequest.newBuilder().setFileContainingSymbol(name).build())
        .forEach(serviceFileProtoObserver::onNext);
    serviceFileProtoObserver.onCompleted();
    serviceFileLatch.await();
    System.out.println(methods);
```

The follow up question would be given that I have this info, how do I make the call building from JSON input that is to be parsed to a format used by the GRPC server?